# JPA derived query IsLessThan filter not working with java.sql.Timstamp

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

when using Timestamp in my entity and making a derived query for that, then the resultset is empty in that case.

My Entity is :-

```
@Data
@Entity
public class RetryCandidate {
@Id
private String extId;
rivate transient int maxAllowedRetries;
private Status status = Status.RETRY_PENDING;
@Embedded
private ClientCallbackMetadata clientCallbackMetadata;
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Timestamp createdDateTime;
@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updatedDateTime;

}
```

Repository method:-

```
 Page<RetryCandidate> findByStatusAndUpdatedDateTimeIsBefore(Status status, Timestamp timestamp, Pageable pageable);
```

Derived JPA query(select columns removed):-

```
 select
    retrycandi0_.ext_id as ext_id2_0_
from
    retry_candidate retrycandi0_ 
where
    retrycandi0_.status=? 
    and retrycandi0_.updated_date_time<? 
order by
    retrycandi0_.updated_date_time asc limit ?
```

Values I'm passing in it:-

```
 binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
 binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2021-01-29 09:13:00.011]
```

Sample postgres data:-

```
ext_id                                 status   updated_date_time
MGb070c5ed-50c5-4a53-96d9-aed6eece09af  0       2021-01-29 06:18:11
MG0fe4c8cc-350c-44a0-9769-030950522d85  0       2021-01-29 06:18:11
MG8821dd92-72b5-4feb-b1ca-592475007332  0       2021-01-29 06:18:12
MG096f9657-632f-4819-a36a-e42522bb3fa4  0       2021-01-29 06:18:12
```

This above code gives me empty resultset when it runs, and the query which hibernate generates from above query is manually running in postgres directly, can't find out what's the issue.

Comment: This is not recommended to use `java.sql.Timstamp`. It is mush better to use Java 8: 
 java.time.Instant, java.time.LocalDateTime, java.time.OffsetDateTime and java.time.ZonedDateTime for this purpose.

Comment: Try with findByStatusAndUpdatedDateTimeBefore. By removing Is.

Comment: What is the SQL generated? And what it the timezone of your machine and the one of the server?

Comment: @JensSchauder, i have added the generate JPA query, and i'm doing it on local first by setting the timezone to UTC and this same query runs when i run it on sql workbench with same parameters value.

Comment: @Alien, I tried removing IS, still the same issue and the same query generated.

Comment: There are always at least two timezones involved: that from the client, i.e. your java application and that of your server. After your comment I'm still not sure which has which timezone. Also try with querying with different times in the relative to the time in the data rows, possibly with hour increments, to see if you get any result at all.